# Cite two papers in parentheses

Tags: citing, natbib

I'd like to cite two papers in one parenthesis, like

> (Author1 et al., 2001, Author2 et al., 2004)

But when I use: `(\citet{paper1}, \citet{paper2})` it gives

> (Author1 et al. ( 2001), Author2 et al. (2004))

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: did you try `\cite{paper1,paper2}?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try either

```
(\citealt{paper1,paper2})
```

or

```
(\citealp{paper1,paper2})
```

depending on whether or not you want a comma between the author's name and the corresponding year. (The second instruction can, in fact, be simplified to `\citep{paper1, paper2}`. I slightly prefer `(\citealp{paper1,paper2})`, though, as it preserves a syntactic symmetry with `(\citealt{paper1,paper2})`.)

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{thoughts.bib}
@article{paper1,
   author = "Author1 and Misc2 and Misc3",
   title  = "Thoughts",
   journal= "Circularity Today",
   year   = 2001,
}
@article{paper2,
   author = "Author2 and Misc4 and Misc5",
   title  = "Further thoughts",
   journal= "Circularity Today",
   year   = 2004,
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
\verb+\citealt+:\quad (\citealt{paper1,paper2})

\verb+\citealp+:\quad (\citealp{paper1,paper2})

\bibliography{thoughts}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\citep{paper1, paper2}
```

should work.